# Zip Directory with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to zip bunch of folders individually.  The folders contain files.  I wrote a script that seems to work perfectly, except that the resulting zip files are not actually compressed.  THey're the same size as the original directory!

Here is my code:

```
import os, zipfile

workspace = "C:\\ziptest"

dirList = os.listdir(workspace)

def zipDir(path, zip):
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
      zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))

for item in dirList:
  zip = zipfile.ZipFile('%s.zip' % item, 'w')
  zipDir('C:\\ziptest\%s' % item, zip)
  zip.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Python expert, but a quick lookup shows that there is another argument for zip.write such as zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED. I grabbed that from [here](http://effbot.org/librarybook/zipfile.htm). I quote:

> The third, optional argument to the write method controls what compression method to use. Or rather, it controls whether data should be compressed at all. The default is zipfile.ZIP_STORED, which stores the data in the archive without any compression at all. If the zlib module is installed, you can also use zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, which gives you “deflate” compression.

The reference is [here](http://effbot.org/librarybook/zipfile.htm). Look for the constant ZIP_DEFLATED; it's definition:

> The numeric constant for the usual ZIP compression method. This requires the zlib module. No other compression methods are currently supported.

I suppose that means that only default compression is supported... hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you don't just call the shell command, like

```
def zipDir(path, zip):
    subprocess.Popen('7z a -tzip %s %s'%(path, zip))
```

Comment: python has direct zipfile support that is cross-platform and doesn't rely on external programs... that's why.